# How many elementary methods are there to show that a set is infinite ( either countably or not)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity

I'm not asking precisely for the exact number of methods, but rather for the various mathods available to show a set is infinite. I'm interested in a sort of methodological review.

In order to show a set S is countably infinite I think one can :

- show that S has ( at least) one proper subset T such that there is ( at least) one bijection from T to S.
- show that there is a bijection from S to the set of natural numbers

In order to show a set S is uncountably infinite, I think one can :

- show that there is (at least) one  bijection from S to the set of real numbers
- show that there is a function from N ( set of natural numbers) to S such that this function is injective but not surjective ( which would leave some elements of S " alone" and prove that S has more elements than N  has) [ WRONG SUGGESTION ACCORDING TO COMMENTS , SEE BELOW]

I cannot go further.

Are there other available methods?

Comment: There is an injective, but not surjective, map from $\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ .... just take $n\mapsto 2n$.

Comment: Concerning the last bullet: the function $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ prescribed by $n\mapsto2n$ is injective and not surjective. But codomain $S=\mathbb N$ is not uncountable.

Comment: Thanks. I've added a warning in my post.

Comment: Note:  that technique does at least show "infinite", even if it can't be used to show "uncountable".

Comment: I think the question is too broad...there are plenty of techniques that apply in particular cases.  For instance, the arguments that show that particular sets of primes are infinite.  There one (sometimes) uses the ordering on the natural numbers and demonstrates a construction which, given any collection of such primes, produces an even larger example.  But of course such constructions use a lot of structure from arithmetic.

Comment: @lulu. - I may modify the question and ask for " elementary" methods instead.

Comment: I don't think it is a question of "elementary".  Rather, my point was that, in practice, one might have a lot of information about the set in question (like that primes are ordered and all natural numbers are divisible by primes, that sort of thing)...that means we can use techniques which have no broader set theoretic meaning.

Comment: To be fair, just thinking about it set-theoretically:  with techniques like I mentioned, what you are doing is showing that there are injections from any specified finite set into the target set....that's enough to prove infiniteness, clearly. Or, equivalently, you argue that no map from a finite set into your target set can be surjective.

Comment: If a set with a strict ordering (for example a subset of the real numbers) has no maximum, then it has to be infinite.